# Do Thunderbolt to Display Port cables exist?

Tags: thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

Is there any  such cable? I'm trying to connect a monitor with display port connector to a MBA with Thunderbolt port. I know I can use a Display port to Mini-display port cable but I'm wondering if there is any Thunderbolt to Display Port cable so that I can get a better resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be no such thing.

Thunderbolt is an active technology, Display Port is passive.
Adding the required circuitry to one end of such a cable would be pointless - it needs both ends to work.

*Edit: Now I read your question again…*

You have a Thunderbolt machine & a Display Port monitor…

That's Thunderbolt to Display Port not Display Port to Thunderbolt.

In which case DP to DP would be sufficient; the Thunderbolt circuitry would simply be inactive if you used Thunderbolt to Thunderbolt.
Display Port & mini-DP are the same thing, but different sizes.

Comment: So basically a such cable would make no difference, right? The reason why I'm asking is that I've got an LG monitor connected to the mac with a DisplayPort to mini display port cable  and it says that I can't reach the native resolution(2560x1080) so I'm wondering what kind of cable I should use.

Comment: If the monitor is DP, that's the best connection you can get. TB will 'step down' to DP. Knowing what mac it is would help

Comment: thanks @Tetsujin! The device is a late 2014 Macbook Air.

Comment: Then it should be able to manage 2560x1600 - I think the issue might be the ultra wide screen not being correctly recognised. Maybe try SwitchRezX or similar, see if you can persuade it. or hold Alt as you switch to Scaled resolution' in the prefs

Answer (score 2):

Tetsujin's answer is not correct. A display port WILL support resolutions up to 4K with the correct cable. Every high end graphics card have display ports as output. The cable must be certified to support 4K resolution otherwise you will not get 2K resolution support on your LG monitor.

Try this setup: Cable Matters DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort Male to Female Adapter - 6 Inches with a Thunderbolt cable - length of your choice. The adapter plugs into the LG's display port and the female thunderbolt port is connected to the MBA with a male to male thunderbolt cable. Done.

Here is a link to Amazon store to purchase the adapter (Cost is only $9):  [http://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-DisplayPort-Female-Adapter/dp/B014DV2RGG?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014DV2RGG)