# Why can't I use this monitor full resolution at 60hz on my 2013 Mac Pro with OS X Mojave?

Tags: display, hdmi, resolution

https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/uhd-and-wqhd/32-uj590-uhd-monitor-lu32j590uqnxza/#specs

Says 60hz on the site, tried HDMI1, HDMI2, FreeSync, tried various HDMI cables, even bought an HDMI to Thunderbolt cable to try instead of HDMI out of the mac.

What gives?

My old mac mini can drive my 60" TV properly, but my Mac pro can't drive an UHD display? Seems like I should be able to do this....

This is the only resolution I can get 60hz at:

[image: displays]

*EDIT* Answer marked below. For anyone wondering:

[image: thunderbolt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to drive a 4k display at 60 Hz over HDMI, you'll need a GPU supporting HDMI 2.0. The 2013 Mac Pro supports HDMI 1.4 by default.

To get this working, you'll want to use a cable plugged into the DisplayPort connector on the monitor, and into the Thunderbolt 2 ports on the Mac Pro.

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me what exactly I'd need? Thunderbolt --> DisplayPort "there can be no such thing" - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168171/do-thunderbolt-to-display-port-cables-exist

Comment: https://www.dell.com/en-ca/shop/accessories/apd/a7657872?cid=3852&st=&gclid=Cj0KCQiA3IPgBRCAARIsABb-iGKDu6l6clSGMUl8xEn4OeNwygWZBcGN8ScewZ7Oo4fHWd4Jiew6_u4aAj1qEALw_wcB&pdv=c&lid=5635587&VEN1=sa5ANQXom,82727171957,901mtv7630,c,&VEN2=,&dgc=st&dgseg=dhs&acd=1230881379501410&VEN3=630104182789570551 ?

Comment: Yes, that’s the type of cable you need

Answer (score 1):

Got Samsung LU32H850UMUXEN 32 and oh dear 30Hz only with MacbookPro 2018. The solution was that HDMI 1 port on this monitor only supports 30Hz and switching to HDMI 2 did the job. Like the owners manual state.

Comment: Thanks a million! The solution of this problem took me days with my MacBook Air M1 (2020) with macOS Monterey and a Samsung U32J59x. But simply switching the HDMI cable from input 1 to input 2 did the job.